# My .Net app needs local admin rights to run. Why?

Tags: .net

I wrote a WinForms app using .Net and C#. The app accesses DirectoryServices and SQL databases.

The new Win7 workplaces are not allowed to have local admin users and this app will not run.

How can I identify the actions in the app which need local admin rights?

**SOLUTION**
The problem was caused by trying to write to the event log. This was just a nice-to-have so it's gone now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it even start up at all?  I'd make a dummy app that does nothing but show a form and see if that one runs.

Comment: So are you going to at least create an answer to your own question and close it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION** The problem was caused by trying to write to the event log. This was just a nice-to-have so it's gone now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Run the app as a limited user, and check the call stacks of the exceptions you get.

Comment: Not getting that far. Just get 'Program stopped working' message. 

I do have a try/catch in the main form constructor. This is set as the start object.

Comment: Add a catch block in `Main()` or an `Application.ThreadException` handler and display or log the exception.